# cheesesquare app on v23 chrashes when dismissing snackbar

Tags: android, material-design

[cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) is a demonstration app for material design.
When updating `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and consequently the libraries `com.android.support{design|appcompat-v7|cardview-v7|recyclerview-v7}` to version 23 a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183166) appears.
When manually dismissing the snackbar, the app crashes as follows:

```
09-02 17:56:30.883  27476-27476/com.support.android.designlibdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.support.android.designlibdemo, PID: 27476
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.MotionEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(AppBarLayout.java:729)
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(AppBarLayout.java:629)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:357)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:409)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1960)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5868)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5920)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographe
```

The [aforementioned site](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183166) suggests:

> Override the default AppBarLayout.Behavior onInterceptTouchEvent method like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child, 
                                         MotionEvent ev) {
        return ev != null && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, ev);
    }
```

> and apply it to your AppBarLayout.

But I'm not sure what is meant by that.

The most clear suggestion I found is [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183930)

```
    public class AppBarLayoutBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child,
                                         MotionEvent ev) {
        return !(parent != null && child != null && ev != null) 
               || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, ev);
        }
    }
```

> set the behavior:

```
   ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout).getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(new AppBarLayoutBehavior());
```

so I added the class `AppBarLayoutBehavior` and put the line above in the `onCreate` of the class in question. But now I get:

```
09-02 17:49:38.421  23604-23604/com.support.android.designlibdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.support.android.designlibdemo, PID: 23604
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.support.android.designlibdemo/com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
            at com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 23.0.1. of support library